# Is this plant Creeping Jenny (Lysimachia nummularia)

Tags: identification, lawn

I have the following plant growing in a part of my lawn in the UK. I originally thought it was some kind of clover, but after taking some images I wasn't to sure.

A Google reverse image search turned up Creeping Jenny (Lysimachia nummularia). I'm still not 100% convinced so just trying to see if I'm correct or not.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's Creeping Jenny, probably the 'Aurea' form. It's a nasty invasive weed in my part of the US (inexplicably, only the green form is banned in my state. Grrr). Controlling it can be difficult - good luck!